# Ни как не могу сделать вывод в одну строку

Tags: html, css, django

У меня на странице сайта есть код, который я ни как не могу вывести единой строкой:

```
<h3>{{ service.title }}</h3> <ab>продолжительностью около <h7>{{ service.length }}</h7> часов</ab>
```

Я перепробовал всё. Пробовал заключать его в `<div>` устанавливая `display: inline-block`. Пробовал использовать `<p>`. Пробовал и `<span>`. Пробовал устанавливать `white-space` в css. Ни что не даёт результата. Может кто-то подскажет, как это сделать не потеряв отдельные оформления внутренних элементов?

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось проблема была что `<h3>` является заголовком на базовом уровне. Просто создал стиль с аналогичными параметрами и всё стало нормально.